# How to count variable in a row in sas?

Tags: sas

I have a table of this form

```
id1|A| 
id1| |var1
id1|B|var2
id2|C|
```

I would like to count retrieve the data that have all the information for all variables: ie

```
id1|B|var2
```

to perform this task I want to count the number of observations in each row and take only the rows which have full observation:

```
 id|name|age |cntrow
```

---

```
id1| A  |    |2 
id1|    |var1|2
id1| B  |var2|3
id2| C  |    |2
```

Any guess how to perform this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `n` function would work if this were numeric.  Since the data are not, you can use CMISS to find out how many are missing:

```
data have;
infile datalines dlm='|';
input
id $ charvar1 $ charvar2 $ numvar;
vars_missing = cmiss(of _all_)-1; *because vars_missing is also missing at this point!;
put _all_;
datalines;
id1|A| |3
id1| |var1|2
id1|B|var2|.
id2|C| |2
;;;;
run;
```

And then subtract that from the known number of variables.  If you don't know it, you can create `_CHARACTER_` and `_NUMERIC_` arrays and use `dim()` for those to find out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CMISS function. Something along the lines of:

```
Data nomissing missing;
    Set input_dataset;
    if CMISS(of _ALL_)=0 then output nomissing;
    if CMISS(of _ALL_)>0 then output missing;
run;
```

Comment: valid answer as well. Thanks